# Will Power BI connects with Azure search index data?

Tags: azure, datasource, powerbi, azure-cognitive-search

I would like to use our azure search index as data source for Power BI dashboard/report. Is there any azure search service connector available for power bi like document DB connector ?.

I don't know where the data is stored in the Azure Search? Please suggest me a way for connecting the data with power BI.

**Note:** Not asking about the Azure Search Traffic Analytics.https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/visualizing-azure-search-data-with-power-bi/

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Azure search is conmnected as follows: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-azure-search/. You do need to know where your data is / the queries you want to ask. PowerBI dies not give you interactive query through the user UI.

Comment: Did you find any way, currently i found one by using the azure search API to return result and then bind it via http call method in power bi

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are not interested in traffic analytics. I am also assuming that you are not interested in displaying [`index statistics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/get-index-statistics).

The actual structure of the "inverted index" created using Azure Search is not exposed, so there is no way for you to visualize it in PowerBI.

Luis Cabrera
Program Manager
Cloud AI Platform - Microsoft

Comment: Hi Luis Cabrera,
Then How can we get the index data in the Power BI as a data Source?

Comment: Hi Luis,
I think they may expose the data by API, how can I use that API to consume the data in PowerBI using Odata feed?

Comment: As mentioned earlier... it is not possible to extract the index data... you can use the index to search on it (through the different query capabilities) -- but you cannot extract data from the index.